# Range-based for loop on arrays

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
int iArray[16];
int iOtherArray[16];
for ( auto &i: iArray )
{
    iOtherArray[i] = iArray[i];
}
```

Where the for loops through the number of components the array has, not each individual component. Am I understanding the usage for Range-based for loops correctly?

Comment: The [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates over the *elements* not the indexes. It could be solved by using [a range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) to iterate over the range of indexes.

Comment: So I'd need to use the tradition `for ( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )` for this specific example? Nothing cool and short I can do in C++ 17?

Comment: No you just need this `std::copy(std::begin(iArray), std::end(iArray), std::begin(iOtherArray));`.

Comment: And if copy isn't all you mean to do, then there's `std::transform`. In fact, there's a whole algorithm library.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the copy algorithm from the standard library:

```
std::copy(array, array+16, otherArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the range -based loop will give you the element values, not indexes.

For a copy operation like this a range-based loop is a poor choice as you have to keep track of two ranges and want cooresponding elements of each. Just use a normal for loop for this.

```
for(int i = 0; 16 > ndx; ++ndx)
  otherArray[i] = array[i];
```